# How do Outsiders of the Native subtype react to different planes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, planes

One of my favorite races to play in pathfinder is Aasimar. Recently, however, this has caused something of a conundrum in my group, as no one is quite sure what happens when an Outsider with the Native subtype travels to another plane. Looking into this then brought up a few other questions.

So, in the interest of getting those answers, I'm going to be asking a string of questions about the topic, starting with this one. Here are the [second](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18797/how-do-outsiders-respond-to-their-own-planes), [third](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18798/how-do-non-outsiders-respond-to-other-plains), [fourth](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18799/how-do-native-outsiders-respond-to-summoning-spells), and [fifth.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/18800/what-is-a-good-way-to-handle-a-multi-plain-adventure)

What happens when an Outsider with the Native subtype travels to a different plane?
Does it lose the subtype, and gain all the advantages of being an outsider?
And, if so, what does its subtype become, as it's a native of the material plane?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This will start similarly to the second question answer, since it comes from a similar point.*

The confusion comes from the word "Native", which is a bit misleading. The description is:

> **Native Subtype**
>
> This subtype is applied only to outsiders. These creatures have mortal
>   ancestors or a **strong connection to the Material Plane** and can be
>   raised, reincarnated, or resurrected just as other living creatures
>   can be. Creatures with this subtype are **native to the Material Plane**.
>   Unlike true outsiders, native outsiders need to eat and sleep.

(emphasis mine)

So "Native" means "Native of the material plane" rather than "Native from the current plane". As the Material plane works differently than outside planes, Native Outsiders are somehow "less Outsiders" than "real Outsiders".

Based on that, an Outsider (Native) would never lose his Native subtype, as whatever the plane he travels too, he would still be Native from the Material Plane. However, he would gain the Extraplanar subtype while not on the Material Plane (see fourth question answer)

Comment: I remember reading a comment on (I think) the Planeswalker forums that said something like "The Outsider(Native)" subtype should really be renamed "Outsider(mortal), as the "Native to the material plane" line is the least important part of the definition. That pretty much sums it up, I think: the important distinction of the subtype isn't that the outsider is on or from the Prime Material, it's that they're dual-natured and mortal, as this answer says.