# How do Outsiders respond to their own planes?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, planes

Does an Outsider gain the Native subtype while on its home plane, and if so, what does that mean, exactly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The confusion comes from the word "Native", which is a bit misleading. The description is:

> **Native Subtype**
>
> This subtype is applied only to outsiders. These creatures have mortal
>   ancestors or a **strong connection to the Material Plane** and can be
>   raised, reincarnated, or resurrected just as other living creatures
>   can be. Creatures with this subtype are **native to the Material Plane**.
>   Unlike true outsiders, native outsiders need to eat and sleep.

(emphasis mine)

So "Native" means "Native of the material plane" rather than "Native from the current plane". As the Material plane works differently than outside planes, Native Outsiders are somehow "less Outsiders" than "real Outsiders".

An Outsider not from the Material Plane would then not get the Native subtype while on its home plane.

Comment: Correct.  @Zach may be looking for the "extraplanar" subtype, which does come and go depending on whether someone's on their home plane or not - see http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Extraplanar

Comment: I remember reading someone's remark that the "Native" subtype should really be renamed the "Mortal" subtype, since it's the eat-sleep-resurrect bit that's important. I tend to treat it that way in my games.